# Ordenar y encontrar el minimo, listas en archivos de Python

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo txt llamado registros.txt con paises y habitantes

```
Argentina, 50538000, 12
Mexico, 25003045, 34
Nicaragua, 10033009, 39
Chile, 15473100, 22
Brasil, 40382909, 32
```

En el cual me piden que ordene de forma ascendente por poblacion e indique cual tiene menos nacimientos
Lo que yo pense hacer es:

```
lista=[] #Lista vacia
archivo= open("registro.txt", "r")
for linea in archivo:
        pais, habitantes, nacimientos = linea.split(",")
        tupla= (pais, int(habitantes), int(nacimientos))
        lista3.append(tupla)
def get_1elemento(tupla):
    return tupla[1]
def get_2elemento(tupla):
    return tupla [2]
archivo.close()
print("Ordenada: ", sorted(lista3, key=get_1elemento))
print("Minimo: ", min(lista3, key=get_2elemento))
```

Cuando lo pruebo me dice: pais, habitantes, nacimientos = linea.split(",")

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Comment: Primero preguntas el pais luego la cantidad de habintantes luego validas que sea uns string el pais y numero los habitantes si todo va bien entonces creas una variable llamada contenido que sera igual a string vacio abres el archivo lees linea por linea con `readline` haces tu bucle for y luego validas `if pais in linea:` contenido += pais +"," + habitantes+"\n" `else` contendio += linea por ultimo cierras el archivo lo abre nuevamente en modo escritura y le escribes todo lo almacenado en la variable contenido cierras y listo

Comment: Cuando lo hago me dice que no defini las variables pais y tampoco habitantes. Ahi te paso mi codigo

Comment: lista = [] #Lista vacia 
eleg_pais=input("Elegir pais que desea actualizar") #Elegir el pais
nuev_hab=int(input("Ingresar la cantidad de nuevos habitantes")) #Cantidad de habitantes
pais=str(pais)
habitantes= int(habitantes)
contenido= str()
archivo= open("registros.txt", "r")
linea= archivo.readlines()
for linea in archivo:
    if pais in linea:
        contenido += pais + "," + habitantes + "\n"
    else:
        contenido += linea
    
archivo.close()

Comment: porque pais y habitantes son los valores que recojes del usuario :V era un ejemplo tio!

Comment: Ay perdon, no habia entendido!

Comment: espera veo que te esfuerzas

Comment: Es que es una materia no tan orientada a lo que estoy estudiando, me cuesta, y me frustra

Comment: no te preocupes te entiendo ya te publique una respuesta! de como debes hacerlo suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: El error de `not enough values to unpack` te lo da si encuentra una línea que no tenga tres campos separados por dos comas. Muy a menudo esto ocurre porque al final del fichero hay una línea en blanco, que causa el problema. Puedes añadir al principio del bucle for una comprobación: `if not linea: continue`. Eso hace que si la línea está vacía, se salta el resto del código y vuelve al `for` a por la siguiente línea. Así no procesas líneas vacías que causen problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias! No sabia eso. Ahora el codigo me da un error  en esta parte:  print("Minimo: ", min(lista3, key=get_2elemento))

ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Parte 1:** Para ordenar el archivo de forma ascendente:

```
# Abrimos el archivo
lista_ordenada = []
with open("registros.txt", "r") as archivo:
    for linea in archivo:
        datos = linea.strip("\n").split(", ")

        if len(datos) == 2: # Si hay dos datos, asumimos que los nacimientos son 0
            pais = datos[0] # el index 0 sería pais
            habitantes = datos[1] # el index 1 es habitantes
            nacimientos = 0

        elif len(datos) == 3: # Si hay tres datos, cojemos el tercer dato como nacimientos
            pais = datos[0]
            habitantes = datos[1]
            nacimientos = int(datos[2]) # Y por tanto nacimientos es el index 2

        lista_ordenada.append([pais, habitantes, nacimientos]) # sea como sea, añadimos este pais a nuestra lista

# Finalmente, ordenamos el contenido.
lista_ordenada.sort(key=lambda dato: dato[1]) # Recuerda, index 1 es habitantes

# Podemos comprobar el orden alfabético así
for linea in lista_ordenada:
    print("{0}, {1}, {2}".format(linea[0], linea[1], linea[2])) # Tenemos que convertirlo al formato que queremos
```

**Parte 2:** Para conseguir el pais con menos cantidad de nacimientos:

```
# Y podemos encontrar el dato más inferior así
minimo = min(lista_ordenada, key=lambda dato: dato[2])
print("El minimo es: {0}, {1}, {2}".format(minimo[0], minimo[1], minimo[2])) # Convertido a nuestro formato
```

El resultado es:

Comment: Cuando lo pruebo me aparece eso: habitantes = datos[1].strip(",") # el index 1 es habitantes, además eliminamos la coma.

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Siempre asumo que un archivo tiene una estructura de base de datos obviamente saneada. Cuando ocurren errores de index es porque no hay tantos datos como se esperan. Por ejemplo, que no encuentre el dato[1] quiere decir que alguna linea de tu código no tiene habitantes. En cualquier caso, eso lo podemos solucionar con checkeos adicionales.

Comment: Cuando corro el programa aparece esto: Argentina, 50538000, 8
Bolivia, 11384230, 9
Brasil, 40382909, 3
Chile, 15473107, 6
Estados, Unidos, 35922456
Mexico, 25003045, 5
Nicaragua, 10033009, 4
Rusia, 65690234, 2
Rusia, 65690234, 2
Rusia, 65690234, 2
Rusia, 65690234, 2
ï»¿,  50538000, 8
El minimo es: Rusia, 65690234, 2

Comment: Es correcto pero me aparece muchas veces Rusia

Comment: Había un ligero error por no tener en cuenta paises con varias palabras como "Estados Unidos". Eso ya ha sido solucionado. Respecto a lo de Rusia, podrías dar más datos? Con el código que he pegado Rusia solo aparece una vez. Asegúrate de que la **parte 2** de mi código **NO** esta dentro del bucle `for` de la parte 1. Y de que el archivo no tiene lineas vacías.

Comment: Claro, pero el orden tiene que ser por poblacion, que es columna 1, y los datos estan dando por orden alfabetico

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver!!! hay un error de tipeo en lista_ordenada.sort(key=lambda dato: dato[0]) .... es datos

Comment: No es un error de tipeo, originalmente el código debería ser `lista.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])` pero pensé que sería confuso si estás aprendiendo a programar, por eso le puse nombre a la variable. Lo mismo ocurre con los bucles, normalmente se hace `for i in file` pero aquí usamos `for linea in archivo` para entenderlo mejor. Me alegro de que pudieras solucionarlo.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
# variable para validar los datos correctos
paso=False
archivo = "data.txt"
#Elegir el pais
pais=input("Elegir pais que desea actualizar: ")

# bucle para validar que los habitantes sean enteros
while(not paso):
    #Elegir los habitantes
    habitantes=input("Ingresar la cantidad de nuevos habitantes: ")

    #intentamos cambiar el tipo para habitantes a formatos correctos
    try:
        # cambiamos habitantes a int
        habitantes=int(habitantes)
        # si se logra cambiar salimos del bucle cambiando paso a False
        paso=True
    # si no se puede combertir habitantes a int tiramos una execpcion y un mensaje
    except Exception as e:
        print("habitantes debe ser un numero!");

#cambiamos el pais a minuscula para comparar de forma mas eficiente
pais=pais.lower()

# esta variable es para contener todo el texto
content=""

with open(archivo,"r") as f:
    # esta variables es para validar que exista un pais o no
    existe_pais=False
    #hacemos un for que recorrera linea por linea del archivo
    for line in f.readlines():
        # hacemos un split de la linea por ',' obtenemos el primer elemento y lo pasamos a minuscula y validamos que sea igual al pais ingresado
        if pais in line.split(",")[0].lower():
            #si el pais existe en la linea le sumamos a variable content el pais y los nuevos habitantes
            content+= f"{pais.title()} , {habitantes}\n"
            # imprimimos un texto de notificacion
            print(f"se ha modificado los habitantes para: {pais.title()} ahora son {habitantes}")
            # decimos que encontramos el pais cambiando existe_pais a True
            existe_pais=True
        else:
            #si no concide el pais lo agregamos igual que como estaba
            content+=line;
    # crerramos el documento
    f.close()
    # si la varibale pais no a cambido y sigu siendo False es que no encontramos el pais y lo notificamos
    if(not existe_pais):
        print(f"ups! no hemos podido localizar: {pais.title()} en el documento")
        y = input("Deseas agregarlo? si o no? ")
        if(y=="si"):
            content+= f"{pais.title()} , {habitantes}\n"
            print(f"se ha agregado {pais.title()} con {habitantes} habitantes al documento")

# abrimos el documento en modo escritura con alias f
with open(archivo,"w+") as f:
    #escribimos el contenido de content en el documento
    f.write(content)
    # crerramos el documento
    f.close()
```

Comment: Y en caso de que me pidieran que los nacimientos esten al lado de la cantidad de habitantes que tenia anteriormente?